# SQL Server 2012 regex finding match

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server Management Studio and need to find and replace some very large database data in a query.

The format I am needing to remove is:

```
VALUES (XXX,
```

As an example:

```
VALUES (25, 
VALUES (101, 
VALUES (55,
```

I can not seem to find a **regex** in order to do this in SQL find and replace. And I am not very good at trying to make a regex match pattern....

Any help would be great!

**Update**

Sorry what I meant is that I am using the Find and replace under the Edit menu:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to replace `VALUES (XXX,` with empty string

Comment: You might want to put your table structure.

Comment: Oops... Maybe an example of what I am looking for would help. Please check the OP.

Comment: I have deleted my answer as not relevant

Comment: This is a link to supported SSMS regex commands: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms174214.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without more detail about exactly how you're using this regex it is difficult to be sure if this will help or not, but a regex which would match any of those lines would be:

```
VALUES \([0-9]+,
```

The 'VALUES (' bit should just match that as a string (the backslash before the open bracket is so your regex engine knows it is part of the string, and not part of the instructions about searching).  The [0-9] bit says that any digit from 0-9 is valid, and the + bit says there needs to be at least one digit.  You might also want a ^ at the start to indicate it is the start of a line, depending on your use-case.  Note that this will match any number of digits after the bracket, and before the final comma.

Comment: SSMS has a limited regex syntax, so {1,3} do not work. (Tested in SSMS 2014)

Comment: Ah right... Haven't worked with SMSS' dodgy version of regex before.  Updated to use # instead

Comment: Bam.. that got it. Thanks Greg!